# How to transfer an iMovie library from one user(U1) on a mac to another user(U2) on the same mac?

Tags: macos, mac, imovie

I tried copying the library to U1 to U2, but when i did, it said I did not have permissions, even after I enabled them to have read and write privileges set to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You need permissions on the folder hierarchy you are trying to write to, not just the file.

Any admin can do this by manually adding ACLs [[access control lists]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list) - but you don't need to go to all that trouble for one simple file move…

- Login to account U1, **copy** the file to `/Users/Shared/`
  [if it's on the same volume, hold Opt as you drag it to force a copy rather than move]
- Login to account U2, **move** the file to its intended destination.
  [If it's on the same volume, just drag it, no keypress]

Comment: After I copy over the library is it safe to delete U1, since I dont use it anymore, and it takes up like 20-40 GB

Comment: If you don't need a copy, just move it both times.

Comment: All right<filler>